# Quickest way to find closest set of point

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I have three arrays of points:

```
A=[[5,2],[1,0],[5,1]]

B=[[3,3],[5,3],[1,1]]

C=[[4,2],[9,0],[0,0]]
```

I need the most efficient way to find the three points (one for each array) that are closest to each other (within one pixel in each axis).

What I'm doing right now is taking one point as reference, let's say `A[0]`, and cycling all other B and C points looking for a solution. If `A[0]` gives me no result I'll move the reference to `A[1]` and so on. This approach as a huge problem because if I increase the number of points for each array and/or the number of arrays it requires too much time to converge some times, especially if the solution is in the last members of the arrays. So I'm wondering if there is any way to do this without maybe using a reference, or any quicker way than just looping all over the elements.

The rules that I must follow are the following:

- the final solution has to be made by only one element from each array like: `S=[A[n],B[m],C[j]]`
- each selected element has to be within 1 pixel in X and Y from ALL the other members of the solution (so `Xi-Xj<=1` and `Yi-Yj<=1` for each member of the solution).

For example in this simplified case the solution would be: `S=[A[1],B[2],C[1]]`

To clarify further the problem: what I wrote above it's just a simplify example to explain what I need. In my real case I don't know a priori the length of the lists nor the number of lists I have to work with, could be A,B,C, or A,B,C,D,E... (each of one with different number of points) etc. So I also need to find a way to make it as general as possible.

Comment: Take a look there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

Comment: Purely Python 3 or can you use additional libs ?

Comment: I'm open to additional libs if it can make the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requirement:

> each selected element has to be within 1 pixel in X and Y from ALL the other members of the solution (so `Xi-Xj<=1` and `Yi-Yj<=1` for each member of the solution).

massively simplifies the problem, because it means that for any given (*x*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>i</sub>), there are only nine possible choices of (*x*<sub>j</sub>, *y*<sub>j</sub>).

So I think the best approach is as follows:

- Copy *B* and *C* into [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).
- Iterate over *A*. For each point (*x*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>i</sub>):

  - Iterate over the values of *x* from *x*<sub>i</sub>−1 to *x*<sub>i</sub>+1 and the values of *y* from *y*<sub>i</sub>−1 to *y*<sub>i</sub>+1. For each resulting point (*x*<sub>j</sub>, *y*<sub>j</sub>):

    - Check if (*x*<sub>j</sub>, *y*<sub>j</sub>) is in *B*. If so:

      - Iterate over the values of *x* from [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)(*x*<sub>i</sub>, *x*<sub>j</sub>)−1 to [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)(*x*<sub>i</sub>, *x*<sub>j</sub>)+1 and the values of *y* from max(*y*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>j</sub>)−1 to min(*y*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>j</sub>)+1. For each resulting point (*x*<sub>k</sub>, *y*<sub>k</sub>):

        - Check if (*x*<sub>k</sub>, *y*<sub>k</sub>) is in *C*. If so, we're done!
- If we get to the end without having a match, that means there isn't one.

This requires roughly *O*(len(*A*) + len(*B*) + len(*C*)) time and *O*(len(*B*) + len(*C*) extra space.

---

**Edited to add** (due to a follow-up question in the comments): if you have *N* lists instead of just 3, then instead of nesting *N* loops deep (which gives time exponential in *N*), you'll want to do something more like this:

- Copy *B*, *C*, etc., into sets of tuples, as above.
- Iterate over *A*. For each point (*x*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>i</sub>):

  - Create a set containing (*x*<sub>i</sub>, *y*<sub>i</sub>) and its eight neighbors.
  - For each of the lists *B*, *C*, etc.:

    - For each element in the set of nine points, see if it's in the current list.
    - Update the set to remove any points that aren't in the current list *and* don't have any neighbors in the current list.
  - If the set still has at least one element, then — great, each list contained a point that's within one pixel of that element (with all of those points also being within one pixel of each other). So, we're done!
- If we get to the end without having a match, that means there isn't one.

which is much more complicated to implement, but is linear in *N* instead of exponential in *N*.

Comment: So this approach seems to work pretty well with the three list but I need some clarification: Why in the first loop you iterate from xi−1 to xi+1 and in the next  from max(xi, xj)−1 to min(xi, xj)+1? What if I have a fourth list D=[[4,2],[0,0],[0,10]]

Comment: @GiovanniMariaStrampelli: In the outer loop you're looking for points in B that are "within range" of the point in A; in the inner loop you're looking for points in C that are "within range" of the point in A *and* the point I found in B. As for what to do if you have a fourth list . . . that's a bit tricky. This approach can be extended for any fixed number of lists, *but* its time complexity is exponential in the number of lists. I'll edit my answer later to explain how you can rework this approach to be linear in the number of lists.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are finding the solution with a *bruteforce* algorithm which has a O(n2) complexity. If your lists contains 1000 items, your algo will need 1000000 iterations to run... (It's even O(n3) as tobias_k pointed out)

Like you can see there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem, you could improve it by using a *divide and conquer* algorithm, which would run in a O(n log n) time.

You should search for [Delaunay triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) and/or [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) implementations.

> NB: if you can use external libs, you should also consider taking a look at the scipy lib: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html

Comment: Actually, OP's problem is a bit different, as they do not want any pair of two points, but exactly one point from each of the three lists. Consequently, complexity would be even O(n³) (n being the number of points in each set, not the total number of points, though)

Comment: yeah, you're right, but isn't it the same algo which is repeated once for each list? i'm not sure I understood this problem right tough.

Comment: Sorry if the problem is not clear but @tobias_k got it right, let me know how I can clarify further the problem.

Comment: No, I don't think you can make it clearer... Still, could'nt you use voronoi to achieve this? For example on an aggregation of your list, then you iterate on the resulting list until you find a point that is in the desired original list?